# read specific number of chars in c

Tags: c, string

Hello i'd like to read from the user a string (no matter how many chars he gives) but i want to keep and store only 10 of them.

For example:

User types: Hello my name is Nick.

And store only: Hello my n

Thank you.

Comment: This seems simple, what have you tried?

Comment: @WhozCraig Please don't suggest using `scanf()`.

Comment: @H2CO3 the format string "%10c" accomplishes what the OP asked about. With a buffer 11 chars wide there is no risk of buffer overflow.

Comment: @StoryTeller I know, it's just then OP will use `scanf()` for everything, and it won't do what he think it does, and then he'll complain about it, and then..., and then...

Comment: @H2CO3, and then he'll be back to SO? :)

Comment: @H2CO3 so `fgets()` is a silver bullet then?

Comment: @WhozCraig Pretty much. Of course, every function in the C standard library has its advantage, but for simply getting a fixed amount of user input, `fgets()` is safe and fine.

Comment: @H2CO3 Ok then, only one more thing I'm curious about. when *would* you use `scanf()`, if ever, if everything above is the case?

Comment: @WhozCraig No, `readline` (the library) is a silver bullet or `getline` (the function now included in POSIX/SUS) the cheap and easy way to fake it.

Comment: @WhozCraig Consider if you have, for example, formatted input in a file, like `H2CO3 CarbonicAcid 43549 1994/06/28` - then you'd want `fscanf()` to parse it for you so you don't have to write a lot of spaghetto code.

Comment: @H2CO3 but thats `fscanf()` pooring data from a file. I mean its counterpart, `scanf()`. Would you *ever* use it?

Comment: @WhozCraig Consider `cat theDataFileIWasTalkingAbout | ./myprog` :P

Comment: @H2CO3 - However one wouldn't know to use it in that case, because they were always told not to. ;) It's always safest to just not do something that's potentially unsafe. That's how Window "protects" users from themselves... I think it's safer still to educate people on all given tools and let them make intelligent decisions.

Comment: @H2CO3 don't misunderstand. It isn't the only lib function that has grown beyond its measured need, to be sure. If you feel it no longer serves the purpose it once did (if ever, as far as that goes), its perfectly reasonable to simply say "I wouldn't." There are some functions that fall into that class for some people, other functions that fall into that class for *most* people. I've concur with *almost* (=P) all your posts, and know you know wtf you're doing. I hope my inquiry into whether *this* function belongs in that class as far as you're concerned isn't taken incorrectly.

Comment: @WhozCraig I mean, it's not wise to say that it's inutile and it is always to be avoided, because it's not true. It is true, however, that one should *generally* try to avoid it, and most problems can *generally* be solved without `scanf()`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thats kind of what I got from you; not something you generally use, as there are usually better ways. Thanks for the patience with my onion-peeling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only if you googled it...

```
char buf[11];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
```

11 char = 10 char plus the terminating NUL.

Comment: +1 - `if you googled it`... that pretty much sums it up.

Comment: @Mike Yeah. Unfortunately... :-((

Answer (score 2):

```
char mystr[11];
scanf("%10[^\n]", mystr);
```

You can use `scanf()` to do what you want, but you need to be careful with the format string. Note I'm using a `10` to make sure we don't take more then 10 characters (which will fit into the buffer of size 11). Also I'm telling it with `[\n]` to read everything until it sees a newline (or 10 chars, which ever is first).

Answer (score 2):

Use `scanf` with a specially-crafted format string:

```
char name[11];
scanf("%10[^\n]%*[^\n]", name);
getchar();
```

Some explanations:

- 11 elements in the array - you know why
- `[^\n]` means "name can contain anything except the newline character" - as opposed to a more conventional `%s` - "name can contain anything except space characters"
- `*` means "read but not store"
- `getchar` at the end consumes the end-of-line character (suggestion by @DanielFischer)

Such a complicated format string is needed because you want to read 10 characters and discard the rest. Alternatively, you could use `fgets` followed by some hack to discard characters until end-of-line.

Comment: Cute. If you must use `scanf` this is nice because it gaurantees to leave the input stream in a simple and well understood state. Of course, if you wight want more data from the end of the string you're going to have to be rather more clever.

Comment: A problem with the format is that the `\n` consumes not only a newline, it consumes an entire sequence of white space, so the `scanf` will only return when the next non-whitespace character is found. Better leave the `\n` out and use a `getchar()` to consume it after the `scanf`.

Comment: `getchar()` doesn't take an argument, you were thinking of `int getc(FILE *stream)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char buf[11];
scanf("%10[^\n]",buf);
```

Comment: downvoter: Could you explain the cause?

Comment: While it wasn't my downvote, I would be reluctant to recommend this without some eplanation. Many users, especially beginners, may be surprised by the state of the input string after this finishes. See [anatolyg's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14285895/2509) for a alternative.

Comment: Code should have some explanation along with it...especially with something as obtuse as scanf codes.